# How do I keep my application running constantly?

Tags: java, gradle, google-api, gmail-api

I am coding an application which should read gmails, answer them and log information.
Right now I run my code via terminal "gradle run". I have a question that, if I wanted this application to run 24/7 how can I achieve this. Does google have some kind of Cloud Services I could use and how would it work then..
I dont understand that on the server side, someone would constantly type "gradle run" into terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a scheduler that runs your application. See https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs-on-schedule or https://cloud.google.com/scheduler